# Exception while Installing Spinnaker

Tags: spinnaker

I am trying to install Spinnaker but facing issue every time. 
1. Tried to deploy using Google Launcher it is not starting anything on port 9000
2. Now trying to install using steps mentioned in https://github.com/spinnaker/spinnaker. Here I ../spinnaker/dev/run_dev.sh I am getting an exception

```
Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is com.netflix.astyanax.connectionpool.exceptions.NoAvailableHostsException: NoAvailableHostsException: [hos
t=None(0.0.0.0):0, latency=0(0), attempts=0]No hosts to borrow from
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredMethodElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:661)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:331)
```

I have also installed Cassandra (Using steps https://hostpresto.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-apache-cassandra-on-ubuntu-14-04/)  and have checked I am able to do cqlsh.

Any help please

Thanks,
Amol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Google Spinnaker Cloud Launcher indeed appears to be broken. I recently tried several times to deploy Spinnaker using it and experienced the same issues as you.

When you say:

> Now trying to install using steps mentioned in https://github.com/spinnaker/spinnaker.

do you mean you're setting up the development environment? That's meant to be used when you actually want to write code for Spinnaker, not for normal use of the project.

The recommended way of getting a running Spinnaker installation is to use [Halyard](https://www.spinnaker.io/setup/install/halyard/), the Spinnaker deployment tool.

Comment: Thanks @mdirkse. Now I am trying to install using Halyard. and Stuck with another issue. Now Installation wants openJDK-8 which does not work on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS and on Google Cloud next option which I have is version 16. And Spinnaker installation does not work on on any other version.

Comment: Strange, I provisioned a GCP VM with 14.04, installed halyard according to the docs and it worked fine, including the install of JDK 8. It should be available.

Comment: Was able to install after I installed oracle JDK manually and then disable autorun in hal deploy apply. Then it created a script. I commented the JDK install section there. It worked after that.  Thanks For your help